# Using Jquery select radio otpions from dictionary

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, django, django-templates

I have a HTML template which has Multichoice Question with options and Essay type questions.

The user's answers are saved in model called Sitting in user_answers field as

```
sitting.user_answers = 
    {"424": "1527", "319": "adadadf", "203": "786", "437": "1572", "383": "1429"}
```

The first number is the question_id and and second is the answer_id(selected option) or answer itself (incase essay type question).

I am able to display the questions in one template using the following code:

**views.py**

```
if self.sitting.get_first_question() is False:
                
                questions= MCQuestion.objects.filter(question_ptr_id__in=self.sitting._question_ids()).prefetch_related('answer_set__question')
                
                essayquestions= Essay_Question.objects.filter(question_ptr_id__in=self.sitting._question_ids())
                answerdetails = Sitting.objects.filter(id=self.sitting.id)
                print(answerdetails)
                return render(self.request, 'dashboard/exam-review.html', {'questions': questions,'essayquestions': essayquestions,'form': True})
```

**Template**

```
{% for question in questions %}
     
      <div class="row mt-2 mb-4 shadow-1" style="background: #ececec">
        
          <div class="col-md-10">
              <input type=hidden name="question_id" value="{{ question.id }}" class="question_id">
              <div class="panel-heading">                          
                  
                  <p class="panel-title mb-2 mt-2" >
                   
                     <li style="list-style-type: none;" class="mb-1 mt-1"><strong>  {% autoescape off %}{{ question.content }}{% endautoescape %} </strong></li>
  
                   
                      {% if question.figure %}
                      <div class="row mb-1">
                      <img src="{{ question.figure.url }}" alt="{{ question.content }}" />
                      </div> 
                      {% endif %}
                                     
                    {% if question.questionmarks %}
                    <div class="row ml-1" >                      
                       <p style="font-size:0.8rem"><b>Marks :</b>  {{ question.questionmarks }}</p>                      
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
              </div>
              
              <div class="panel-body ">
              
              <ul class="mb-2" style="list-style-type: none;">
                      {% regroup question.answer_set.all by get_content_display as answer_list %}
                    
                      {% for answers in answer_list %}
                      <span>{{ section.grouper }}</span>
                          {% for answer in answers.list %}
                         //What to write here ???
                             <li class="list-group-item quiz-answers" >
                             <span><label for="id_answers_0"><input type="radio" name="answers_{{question.id}}" value="{{answer.id}}" style="margin-right:10px;" id="{{answer.id}}" required>
                               {{answer.content}}  </label>  </span></li>                              
                          {% endfor %}
                      {% endfor %}
                  </ul>
             
               
            </div>
          </div> 
          
         
      </div>
      
  {% endfor %}
 

  {% if essayquestions %}
  
  {% for question in essayquestions %}
     
  <div class="row mt-2 mb-4 shadow-1" style="background: #ececec">
        
          <div class="col-md-10">
              <input type=hidden name="question_id" value="{{ question.id }}" class="question_id">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                 
                  <p class="panel-title mb-1" >
                  
                     <li style="list-style-type: none;"><strong>  {% autoescape off %}{{ question.content }}{% endautoescape %} </strong></li>
  
                     <div class="row mb-1">
                      {% if question.figure %}
                      <img src="{{ question.figure.url }}" alt="{{ question.content }}" />
                      {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    
                    {% if question.questionmarks %}
                    <div class="row mb-1" >                       
                       <p style="font-size:0.8rem"><b>Marks :</b>  {{ question.questionmarks }}</p>                      
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                
                    </p>
                    <div class="panel-body mb-2">
                        <ul class="list-group mb-2" style="list-style-type: none;">
                            
                            <li class="list-group-item quiz-answers mb-1">
                                <span><textarea name="answers" cols="40" rows="5" style="width:100%" id="answer_{{question.id}}" required>
                                </textarea>  </span>
                            </li>
                            
                        </ul>
                    </div>
               
                
              </div>
              
            </div>
        </div>
        
            
    {% endfor %}   

  {% endif %}
```

Could I use Jquery to fill the radio option using dictionary object ?